# How to correctly handle a call function in a function with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm trying to understand how to handle some events with javascript, in particular if a specific event is triggered the current function calls another function. At onLoad the javascript creates the first select the data from the first object. Then if I select the voice with value "Iphone" is called another function for create the second menu with some prices. My main problem is that my solution seems quite ugly, and also when i click more than one time on the button it creates every times the same second select.

```js
//global objects
var product = [
  {name: "Samsung"},
  {name: "Iphone"},
  {name: "Alcatel"},
  {name: "Sony"}
]

var productPrice = [
  {name: "Samsung", price: 190},
  {name: "Iphone", price: 290},
  {name: "Alcatel", price: 65},
  {name: "Sony", price: 330}
]

var main = function() {
  var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('#select-1');
  
  $(product).each(function() {
    sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.name).text(this.name));
  });
  
  $('.press').click(function() {
    if ($("#select-1 option:selected").text() == "Iphone") {
      handleEvent();
    }
    
    if ($("#select-1 option:selected").text() != "Iphone") {
      $("#risposta").remove();
    }
  });
}

function handleEvent() {
  var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('#select-2');
  
  $(productPrice).each(function() {
    sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.name).text(this.price));
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  main();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select-1">
</div>
<div id="select-2">
</div>
<button class="press">Click</button>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9duy6k5k/10/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: the reason that it created another element is that `handleEvent()` function is creating an element.

Comment: and to continue on @JericCruz's point, you basically have two options: 1) remove the list always before appending 2) toggle visibility (eg. css class) instead of append

Comment: @Jeric Cruz I know, cause the function that I have declared creates every time the second select. I have imagined something like this code for handle this event, but it seems not worth. How can I organize better my functions for avoid these events problems? I mean for call just one time the function that creates the second select, and of course remove that when i click on other select values.

Comment: `$("#select-1 option:selected")` probably needs to be `$("#select-1").find("select option:selected")`

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/qu9zs2h1/ , Just make sure the select isn't already created, just use a class or an id to make sure it hasn't already been appended

Comment: are you saying that do you want to have the 2nd select element to be dynamic?  so when you select the first option in first select element, content of the 2nd select will be base on the 1st select?

Comment: Okay, I think I have understand well. But for example if I decide to click first on "Samsung" value and click the button, when i click on Iphone value and I click the button something goes wrong. It depends probably by my conditional statement on $('.press').click(function(). And it's quite strange cause I have put a console.log and the call function in the if statement works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is not 100% clear to me however I gather you want to generate a `select` tag on `dom` ready event which you have already. When you select the option `iPhone` and hit the `Click` button you want to generate another `select` tag with the new options from your variable.

### First option

Is what I have provided below. Its basically your code but with an extra if statement

jsFiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/qu9zs2h1/2/

Javascript

```
//global objects
var product = [{
  name: "Samsung"
}, {
  name: "Iphone"
}, {
  name: "Alcatel"
}, {
  name: "Sony"
}]

var productPrice = [{
  name: "Samsung",
  price: 190
}, {
  name: "Iphone",
  price: 290
}, {
  name: "Alcatel",
  price: 65
}, {
  name: "Sony",
  price: 330
}]

var main = function() {
  var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('#select-1');

  $(product).each(function() {
    sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.name).text(this.name));
  });

  $('.press').click(function() {
    if ($("#select-1 option:selected").text() == "Iphone") {
      handleEvent();
    }

    if ($("#select-1 option:selected").text() != "Iphone") {
      $("#risposta").remove();
    }
  });
}

function handleEvent() {
  // We still run the handleEvent function however, if check to see
  // if the second select option has been generated by checking a 
  // class
  if (!$('.prices').length) {
    var sel = $('<select class="prices">').appendTo('#select-2');
    $(productPrice).each(function() {
      sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.name).text(this.price));
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  main();
});
```

Html

```
<div id="select-1">
</div>
<div id="select-2">
</div>
<button class="press">Click</button>
```

I had to add the class `prices` to your second `select` but that is just a class you can rename which is used to see if that element already exists.

### The second option (Probably the better way)

Is you generate everything on `dom` ready and hide what you want at the start and then simply `show` elements when you want, like so

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qu9zs2h1/5/

Javascript

```
//global objects
var product = [{
  name: "Samsung"
}, {
  name: "Iphone"
}, {
  name: "Alcatel"
}, {
  name: "Sony"
}]

var productPrice = [{
  name: "Samsung",
  price: 190
}, {
  name: "Iphone",
  price: 290
}, {
  name: "Alcatel",
  price: 65
}, {
  name: "Sony",
  price: 330
}]

// On document ready run this script
$(function() {
    $('.jshidden').removeClass('jshidden').hide();

  var $select1 = $('#select-1');
  var $select2 = $('#select-2');
  var $sel1 = $('<select>').appendTo($select1);
  var $sel2 = $('<select>').appendTo($select2);

  $(product).each(function() {
    $sel1.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.name).text(this.name));
  });

  $(productPrice).each(function() {
    $sel2.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.price).text(this.price));
  });

  $('.press').click(function() {
    if ($select1.find(":selected").text() == "Iphone") {
      $select2.show();
    }

    if ($select1.find(":selected").text() != "Iphone") {
      $select2.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Html

```
<div id="select-1">
</div>
<div id="select-2" class="jshidden">
</div>
<button class="press">Click</button>
```

P.S. just a little something, anything which is referring to a variable which is a `jQuery` element should start with a `$` it just helps read the code.

Just a quick update, you can also reduce the `.press` code with this code

```
$('.press').click(function() {
  var iPhoneCheck = $select1.find(":selected").text() == "Iphone";
    $select2.toggle(iPhoneCheck);
  });
```

`jQuery.toggle` takes in a bool value to either display the target or hide the target

Comment: Thank you @Canvas, both solutions are nice! So in the second version you have simplified and replaced the call function with more specific if statements. In your opinion which is the best choice as code structure?

Comment: The second option would be the best one as you don't modify the `dom` again. Also if any of the provided answers are correct make sure to tick the answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
//global objects
var product = [
  {name: "Samsung"},
  {name: "Iphone"},
  {name: "Alcatel"},
  {name: "Sony"}
];

var productPrice = [
  {name: "Samsung", price: 190},
  {name: "Iphone", price: 290},
  {name: "Alcatel", price: 65},
  {name: "Sony", price: 330}
];

var main = function() {
  var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('#select-1');
  $(product).each(function() {
    sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.name).text(this.name));
  });
  
  $('.press').click(function() {
    var sel2 = document.getElementById('select-2');
    var selectedOption = $("#select-1 option:selected").text();
    if (selectedOption == "Iphone") {
      // check if the select was already added
      if(sel2.children.length == 0)
        handleEvent();
    }
    else {
      // I think here you wanted to remove the second select that was added for iphone option
      sel2.innerHTML = '';
    }
  });
}

function handleEvent() {
  var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('#select-2');
  $(productPrice).each(function() {
    sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.name).text(this.price));
  });
}

// if you already have a declared function, there is no need to an anonymous function
// just call the main function directly
$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select-1">
</div>
<div id="select-2">
</div>
<button class="press">Click</button>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are missing javascript and jquery dom selectors? you can just use `$`, also removing the select and re-appending it is silly to do, you should just check the length and if it exists do nothing

Comment: I just hadn't realized i was mixing the two selectors, just didn't pay attention, no special reason. I removed the select appended because I assumed that when another option was selected in the first select (samsung, acatel, sony),  the appended select should be removed as in the snippet of the question there was a line of code trying to do something like that. ($("#risposta").remove();)

Comment: Okay, I have realized what I missed as logic: i forgot to make a correct if statement for add/remove the second select. So you have declared sel2 and you have controlled if #select-2 empty with with his children.length. That's nice! Any suggestions also for improve and minimize the current code? Thank you again guys!

Comment: There is something I didn't understand. All that prices that are being appended to when I choose "Iphone" (190, 290, 65, 330). Are they really supposed to be added? Or just 290 that is the price for Iphone? One suggestion is that you don't need the two objects: product and productPrice. "productPrice" already have all you need. If you really need to append all the prices as i am asking, you just use an array in the price property of the productPrice object.

Comment: Thank you for the advices @jplobianco i'll use just one object so.